# File handling in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and was wondering what command to use to remove the file path and extension. for example if my file is ./data/input/myfile.js how can i strip it out to only have myfile (without path and extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node.js, you would use the `path` module and use [`path.basename()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) in that module:

```
const path = require('path');

let basename = path.basename('./data/input/myfile.js');
console.log(basename);    // "myfile.js"
```

FYI, this has nothing to do with TypeScript, this is just a plain node.js question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just started to do coding on type script and I am still confused about nodejs, type script

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a javascript question and not a typescript question ;)

Use the built-in [path library](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) of node, which covers all the edge cases of filesystems

Comment: Parsing paths by splitting them using arbitrary separators is not advisable. The example works fine on Linux and macOS (and any other Un*x flavour) but it doesn't work on Windows (because Windows paths use ``\`` as separator and they are also prefixed by the drive). This approach also doesn't handle the multiple consecutive occurrences of the separator, relative paths etc. Use the functions provided by the [`path` module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/path.html) of Node.js.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using path helped.